# Cybersecurity "Airport model"

Tags: authentication, network, firewalls

For the last few months, I have heard about a next generation model of Cybersecurity called the "Airport model."

Does anyone have more information about it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Airport model is a concept where the network infrastructure is split up to different zones secured with different levels of security that share information between the zones. Airport security is very similar and thus the name.

Just like in an Airport there is a "control tower" that is in charge of detecting any anomalies or incidents in the network. This "control tower" is usually placed in the SOC(Security Operations Center) team or under the CERT(Computer Emergency Response Team).

You can view a diagram of the model [here](https://www.wavestone.com/app/uploads/2017/07/generation-cybersecurity-model.pdf) in page 2 paragraph 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Inside the airport zones, there is a security layer called bubble? What does it mean?

Comment: I am finding it hard to find anything about the bubble layer but I can guess it is the layer that provides a connection between the zone and the other zones.

Comment: Fanar, you just asked another question. Make a new question, don't use this one for it. This one is answered. The other one will get more attention. You can link to this one and back for clarity.

Comment: ***Is*** an airport control tower responsible for detecting security anomalies? I thought they were in charge of directing planes on the ground (because of the view), and the security force is managed from a concrete bunker somewhere.

Comment: @immibis - The "control tower" is also in charge of detecting any abnormal activity and then pass it on to the relevant team. This abnormal activity can be an extra plane in the radar or a plane about to crash. This is the reason the "control tower" is placed in either the SOC team or CERT.